# c# - Sorting Multiple String arrays with Quicksort

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, quicksort

Sorry for the vague title but I'll try and describe what my problem as best as I can below.

Basically I have 5 string arrays that all hold data relevant to the same index in the other arrays. For example, element 5 in array 1 corresponds to element 5 in arrays 2, 3, 4 and 5.

What I have done is used the Quicksort algorthim to sort array 1 into alphabetical order. The problem is that when the array is sorted, no longer do elements in the other arrays correspond since the other arrays haven't been sorted.

What I need is some way to swap the same elements around in the other 4 arrays as has been down to array 1. For example, if element 2 in array 1 is swapped to element 55, then element 2 in the other 4 arrays need to be swapped to element 55 in their array and vice versa.

The end goal is to display all the data in a specific element across all 5 arrays.

Below I have added the quicksort algorithm I'm using and added 3 example arrays that need sorting:

```
   string[] array1 = {"z","y","x","a"};
   string[] array2 = {"26","25","24","1"}; 
   string[] array3 = { "black","yellow","white","red" };


   // The first 2 arrays should clarify my point further. 

  // I use Quicksort to sort array 1 


   public static void QuicksortSTRING(IComparable[] elements, int left, int right)  
   {        
         int i = left, j = right;  
         IComparable pivot = elements[(left + right) / 2];  

         while (i <= j)  
         {  
            while (elements[i].CompareTo(pivot) < 0)  
            {  
              i++;  
            }

            while (elements[j].CompareTo(pivot) > 0)
            {
              j--;
            }

            if (i <= j)
            {
                // Swap
                IComparable tmp = elements[i];
                elements[i] = elements[j];
                elements[j] = tmp;

                i++;
                j--; 
            }
        }

        // Recursive calls

        if (left < j)
        {
           QuicksortSTRING(elements, left, j);
        }

        if (i < right)
        {     
           QuicksortSTRING(elements, i, right); 
        }
    }
```

If you need any other info just ask.

Comment: All arrays will have same length ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad Yes, all the arrays are exactly the same length.

Comment: Are you required to write your own Quicksort for some reason? Or are you allowed to use .Net's sorting?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes I have write my own quicksort method. This code is part of a college assignment.

Comment: Please note that real general purpose quick-sort algorithm to be O(n log n) would pick the pivot at random rather than just middle element, unless you have some statistical assumptions about your input data.

Answer (score 2):

It’s better to put the three related strings into a single object:

```
sealed class RelatedInformation     // or struct, you decide
{
    public string First;
    public string Second;
    public string Third;
}
```

and then sort a list of those objects:

```
var myList = new List<RelatedInformation>();
// insert code that populates the list here
myList.Sort((a, b) => a.First.CompareTo(b.First));
```

or, if it needs to be an array:

```
var myArray = /* obtain the RelatedInformation[] here */;
Array.Sort(myList, (a, b) => a.First.CompareTo(b.First));
```

Additionally, there is no need for you to implement Quicksort yourself (unless this is homework? :)). You can just use [Array.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [List<T>.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with a lambda expression that specifies your sort criterion.

You don’t even need to implement the `IComparable<T>` interface if you use the above code. However, if the `RelatedInformation` class (or struct) is used in many places that have something to do with their ordering, it may be wise to implement it anyway; then you can ditch the lambdas:

```
sealed class RelatedInformation : IComparable<RelatedInformation>
{
    public string First;
    public string Second;
    public string Third;

    public int CompareTo(RelatedInformation other)
    {
        return First.CompareTo(other.First);
    }
}

// ...

var myList = new List<RelatedInformation>();
// insert code that populates the list
myList.Sort();
```

---

However, since you explicitly asked about **the three-array situation,** here is a solution that will work under that constraint. Instead of sorting any one of the arrays, the idea is to sort *a list of the indexes*. I’m going to use LINQ for this because it’s pretty succint and readable:

```
var sortedIndexes = Enumerable.Range(0, array1.Length)
                        .OrderBy(i => array1[i])
                        .ToArray();

var sortedArray1 = sortedIndexes.Select(i => array1[i]).ToArray();
var sortedArray2 = sortedIndexes.Select(i => array2[i]).ToArray();
var sortedArray3 = sortedIndexes.Select(i => array3[i]).ToArray();
```

Pretty short, huh? Of course, in the call to `OrderBy`, you can specify any other array to sort by.

Do be aware though that this code will throw an exception if any of the arrays is *shorter* than the first one, and it will silently discard items if any of the arrays is *longer* than the first one. One major benefit of the list-of-objects solution is that you do not need to worry about that.

As an added piece of information, the `OrderBy` from LINQ is a *stable sort*; this means that items where `array1` has the same string stay in the same order. `Array.Sort` and `List<T>.Sort` do not have a stable sort.

You can even use this method to sort by multiple criteria; for example, let’s say you want to sort by the strings in `array1`, but whenever `array1` has the same string for some items, you want those items to be sorted by whatever is in `array2`. You can do that using `ThenBy`:

```
var sortedIndexes = Enumerable.Range(0, array1.Length)
                        .OrderBy(i => array1[i])
                        .ThenBy(i => array2[i])
                        .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got these three items of information to sort. Try creating a class to hold them. It can be an inner class inside one of your program classes if you want.

```
   struct MyThing :IComparable {
      char a;
      int b;
      string c;
   }
```

Then make a `List<MyThing>`. Then populate it with your data.

You'll need to implement the [IComparable interface (requiring your own CompareTo method)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320727) for your class, so it knows to sort on `a`, or whatever you want sorted.

Then use the built in [`List.Sort()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx) function or your own quicksort method.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would make more sense if you stored all your related information together in one array, e.g.:

```
var array = new[] { Tuple.Create("z", "26", "black"),
                    Tuple.Create("y", "25", "yellow"),
                    Tuple.Create("x", "24", "white"),
                    Tuple.Create("a", "1", "red") };
```

Then you can sort your array by any key you like and preserving other elements at corresponding positions.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. How would I then use the Quicksort method with this new array?

Comment: @TF7: You'll have to modify your `QuickSort` method to accept `Tuple<string, string, string> elements` and then, when you do comparison, you'll have to access desired part of tuple, e.g. `elements[i].Item1.CompareTo`.

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this by putting all your related strings into a single class, rather than keeping them all in separate arrays.

For example:

```
public class Demo
{
    public string Key;
    public string S1;
    public string S2;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Key: {0}, S1: {1}, S2: {2}", Key, S1, S2);
    }
}
```

Then when you want to sort that, you need a way to determine which property or properties to use when comparing elements. There are several ways to do this; one is to make your type implement `IComparable<T>`.

However there is another more flexible approach. You can supply to your sort method an `IComparer<T>` object that it can use to compare elements.

Using this, you can "pick out" the member of a class that you want to use when comparing.

Here's a full example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Demo
    {
        public string Key;
        public string S1;
        public string S2;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Key: {0}, S1: {1}, S2: {2}", Key, S1, S2);
        }
    }

    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var list = new List<Demo>
            {
                new Demo {Key = "Z", S1 = "Z1", S2 = "Z2"},
                new Demo {Key = "Y", S1 = "Y1", S2 = "Y2"},
                new Demo {Key = "X", S1 = "X1", S2 = "X2"},
                new Demo {Key = "W", S1 = "W1", S2 = "W2"},
                new Demo {Key = "V", S1 = "V1", S2 = "V2"}
            };

            // Rather than write your own IComparer<Demo> implementation, you can
            // leverage a built-in .Net implementation by using 
            // Comparer<Demo>.Create() as follows:

            var keyComparer = Comparer<Demo>.Create((x, y) => string.Compare(x.Key, y.Key, StringComparison.Ordinal));

            QuicksortSTRING(list, 0, list.Count-1, keyComparer);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", list));
        }

        public static void QuicksortSTRING<T>(IList<T> elements, int left, int right, IComparer<T> comparer)
        {
            int i = left, j = right;
            var pivot = elements[(left + right)/2];

            while (i <= j)
            {
                while (comparer.Compare(elements[i], pivot) < 0)
                {
                    i++;
                }

                while (comparer.Compare(elements[j], pivot) > 0)
                {
                    j--;
                }

                if (i <= j)
                {
                    // Swap
                    T tmp = elements[i];
                    elements[i] = elements[j];
                    elements[j] = tmp;

                    i++;
                    j--;
                }
            }

            // Recursive calls

            if (left < j)
            {
                QuicksortSTRING(elements, left, j, comparer);
            }

            if (i < right)
            {
                QuicksortSTRING(elements, i, right, comparer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've used what you've done and it worked great! I know this may be asking too much  but, now that my data is sorted, how can I make use of the binary search algorithm to find a specific Key value in the list? I have tried doing so but encountered errors. I have to write the binary algorithm myself, can't use built-in functions. If you're willing to help maybe we could contact each other via another means? Thanks for what you've already done.

Comment: @TF7 You should write a new question, showing what you've tried so far, and I or someone else should be able to answer. (P.S. Don't forget to accept the answer and upvote any answers that you find helpful - that's how Stack Overflow works. ;)

Comment: Okay Matthew, thanks for the help. I've just asked the new question now.